# Google Play Account Termination

Tags: google-play, termination, policies, developer-console

Today I recieved a notificiation e mail from Google:

"This is a notification that your Google Play Publisher account has been terminated.

REASON FOR TERMINATION: Prior violations of the Developer Program Policies and Developer Distribution Agreement by this or associated accounts as outlined in previous emails sent to the registered email address(es) of the Publisher account(s).

Google Play Publisher suspensions are associated with developers, and may span multiple account registrations and related Google services.

You can visit the Developer Policy Center to better understand how we enforce Developer Program Policies. If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel this termination may have been in error, please reach out to our policy support team.

Do not attempt to register a new developer account. We will not be restoring your account at this time.

The Google Play Team"

1- I did not recieved any mails before this. There is no previous e mails.
2- I sent a mail to support about this.
3- What should I do now?

Comment: Wait for Google support to respond. No one here can unlock your account.

Comment: Of course but I m really dissapointed now. I think it is very strange that they r talking about mails that they did not send

Comment: How soon did they respond regarding this?

Comment: Trust me, they will never respond. I guess you have to look for alternatives

Comment: it's a bot . so nobody will hear our scream here and there. especially inside the playstore.
i wish your account could be renewed lately. :D
And share a story if you success....